# How to transform jsonSchema to Spark DataFrame schema?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a dataframe and I would like it to be validated against my json schema provided by another app

https://json-schema.org/implementations.html
I don't see any implementations with Spark Scala.

How can I validate my all dataframe with a json schema ?

Comment: Spark scala has there own JSON schema validators have you tried them ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50500032/use-from-json-in-scala-to-parse-multiple-rows-in-a-dataframe   this should tell u enufff

Comment: I just have a jsonSchema which from a js application, with respect the standard 
https://json-schema.org/learn/miscellaneous-examples.html
A lot of language has a lib to validate data with this schema. Which make it a very easy to navigate between multi langage.
I can't digest this json schema in scala.